# Setting icon and logout is missing from phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am able to create users, but how can I log in to created users?

The setting icon and logout are missing from phpMyAdmin.

[image: Annotated phpMyAdmin Screenshot]

Comment: In `config.inc.php`, what is your 'auth_type' set to?

Answer (score 8):

The logout button is only displayed with `auth_type` 'cookie' or 'http'; if yours is set to 'config' then the logout button won't display (because that wouldn't make any sense in that context as the user and password are hardcoded to `config.inc.php`.

Simply edit your `config.inc.php` and change the `auth_type`.

Comment: @JohnDon Please accept this answer if it worked for you. Otherwise, please state why it did not.

Answer (score 1):

My experience has been that this happens when one links to phpMyAdmin from a control panel, rather than logging in directly.

If this is what you have done, then logging out of cPanel (etc) should also log you out of phpMyAdmin.